# Want to ask an advice about jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm new with jquery and want to ask a question, can jquery make something like this pics?

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/11uuedh.jpg]

I don't know what's this was called, so I can't googled it.

Regards, B_S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - check out the [multiselect2side jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multiselect2side).

Comment: wow, thank you very much, Dan Diplo. I was gonna give up lurking in google and finally i find this site.